# select data from DB and Insert new data in front of selected row

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to insert a data into a mysql database, but I need to put some constrains over that insertion. And my code is not working for me.
Basically I have selected "departments" from the mysql db using html select tag and show that in dropdown. And now I want to insert subject and subject code in front of that row which is selected in the drop down. But the problem is my code is not working and show me error please help and checkout code.

This is code for inserting data from mysql database. It work's fine.

```
<code>
<select class="form-control" name="department">
      <?php
      $host="localhost";
$username = 'root';
$password = "";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db('sims',$con);

// Checking connection
if (!$con){
  echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL:. " .mysql_error($con));
  }
else {
     echo("db connect");
}


      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from `sims-reg-department`");
      if($result == FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>
    <option value="<?php '.row[dept-id];'?>"><?php echo $row["dept-name"];?></option>
<?php }
       ?>
        </select>
</code>
```

This section is showing me errors:

```
<code>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$dptname = $_POST["department"] or
$coursename = $_POST["course-name"] and
$coursecode = $_POST["course-code"];
if($coursename=="" or $coursecode=="" )
{
  echo "Please fill all the fields before hit submitting button";
  return true;
}
else
{
$q = "INSERT INTO `sims-reg-department`(`course-name`,`course-code`)VALUES ('$coursename','$coursecode') where '$dptname' LIKE `dept-name`";
     }
$res = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
</code>
```

Comment: You can't put constraints on `INSERT` statements.

Comment: so what i should do..can you give me an appropiate solution?

Comment: Very unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, but it looks like you're trying to update a record instead of inserting a new one. In that case, use the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: ok thank you..i will try that and will let you know.thank's for replying useful tips.